# AWS SNS SMS senderID is behaving somewhat erratically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, sender-id

I'm trying to send alert to clients from our rails application and I would like the sender id to be our company name. I've tried setting the DefaultID using the dashboard, the ruby SDK, and setting the SenderId on each publish. However, in all cases the SenderId randomly (at least I can't find a pattern) changes between "notify", our company name, and a 4 digit code.

I've tried things like setting the default SenderId for the SNS before each publish, I've tried setting after each publish, Ive tried several different Sender ID.

I just can't figure out any reason why it would work sometimes and not others. I've got my setting for sms as transactional. The only thing I can think of is that the NZ (in this case 2 Degrees) could just be failing. I.e. have a bad system. I know there can be country specific rules around SenderIDs and their formats etc. But it works sometimes so surely my settings are alright.